# How to query a xml file using xpath (php) ?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, phpquery

I am trying to query an XML file using XPath. But as return I get nothing. I think I formatted the query false.

> XML

```
<subject id="Tom">
   <relation unit="ITSupport" role="ITSupporter" />
  </subject>
```

> PHP

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
            $role = 'ITSupporter';
           $elements = $xpath-> query("//subject/@id[../relation/@role='".$role."']");              
           foreach ($elements as $element) {    
              $name = $element -> nodeValue;
              $arr[$i] = $name;
              $i = $i + 1;
           }
```

How can I get the id TOM? I want to save it to for example $var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up the Xpath expression:

- Fetch any `subject` element
  `//subject`
- ... with a child element `relation`
  `//subject[relation]`
- ... that has a `role` attribute with the given text
  `//subject[relation/@role="ITSupporter"]`
- ... and get the `@id` attribute of `subject`
  `//subject[relation/@role="ITSupporter"]/@id`

Additionally the source could be cleaned up. PHP arrays can use the `$array[]` syntax to push new elements into them.

Put together:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<subject id="Tom">
  <relation unit="ITSupport" role="ITSupporter" />
</subject>
XML;

$role = 'ITSupporter';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$ids = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//subject[relation/@role='".$role."']/@id") as $idAttribute) {
  $ids[] = $idAttribute->value;
}
var_dump($ids);
```

Output:

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> 
  string(3) "Tom" 
}
```

If you expect only a single result you can cast the it in Xpath:

```
$id = $xpath->evaluate(
  "string(//subject[relation/@role='".$role."']/@id)"
);
var_dump($id);
```

Output:

```
string(3) "Tom"
```

#### XML Namespaces

Looking at the example posted in the comment your XML uses the namespace `http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0` without a prefix. The XML parser will resolve it so you can read the nodes as `{http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0}subject`. Here are 3 examples that all resolve to this:

- `<subject xmlns="http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0"/>`
- `<cpee:subject xmlns:cpee="http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0"/>`
- `<c:subject xmlns:c="http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0"/>`

The same has to happen for the Xpath expression. However Xpath does not have
a default namespace. You need to register an use an prefix of your choosing. This
allows the Xpath engine to resolve something like `//org:subject` to `//{http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0}subject`.

The PHP does not need to change much:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<subject id="Tom" xmlns="http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0">
  <relation unit="ITSupport" role="ITSupporter" />
</subject>
XML;

$role = 'ITSupporter';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register a prefix for the namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('org', 'http://cpee.org/ns/organisation/1.0');

$ids = [];
// address the elements using the registered prefix
$idAttributes = $xpath->evaluate("//org:subject[org:relation/@role='".$role."']/@id");
foreach ($idAttributes as $idAttribute) {
  $ids[] = $idAttribute->value;
}
var_dump($ids);
```

Comment: as a result I get: array(0) { } :(

Comment: Then you have a different XML - maybe with a namespace. Try my example without modifying it (https://3v4l.org/oJLGG).

Comment: Dear @ThW, your code is working! You have been right. But this is the XML file that I have to query: https://3v4l.org/uKTS7. Shouldn't it be the same? :S I want to query all IDs (names) with the ID (for example ITSupporter)

Comment: No, your XML uses a namespace. `//subject` looks for an element in the "empty" namespace. You could think of it as `<subject xmlns=""/>`. I added some explanation and a modified example to the answer.

Comment: Dear @ThW,  I tried your example, it works only when I copy paste it. But when I read the XML code from a file, I get null again. Can you help me please, I really don't get it, what am I doing wrong. I read the XML with: 
> $xml = 'organisation.xml';
> $document = new DOMDocument();
> $document->loadXML($xml);
> $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

Comment: You can not load a file name as an XML string. `DOMDocument::loadXML()` loads an XML string variable, `DOMDocument::load()` loads an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath

```
//subject[relation/@role='".$role."']/@id
```

You were applying the predicate on the `id` attribute and not on the `subject` element.

Comment: Hmm I still get nothing back. :( {
        "taskname": "Read order",
        "employee": "leer",
        "role": "ITSupporter",
        "form": "form1.html",
        "done": 0
    }

Comment: Under Employee should be the Name. But I only get the initial value of my var. The query doesn't save anything

Answer (score 0):

Getting element by id is the same as doing by $role contents.
So, like the followings;
`$xpath->query("//*[@id='$id']")->item(0);`
In other words, @id should be in '[' bracket.